# "A myth come true." Is the base form of "come" legitimate?

Tags: participles, bare-infinitives, predicate, whiz-deletion

source:

> When selected
>
> - Cyclops, ready for your orders.
> - I see it all.
> - Awaiting orders.
> - *A myth **come** true.*
> - Always on standby.
> - Yes, commander?

(https://moapyr.fandom.com/wiki/Cyclops_Walker/Quotes)

Why not "A myth **has come** true" (which I would like to say) or "A myth **came** true" or "A myth **comes** true"?

Is "A myth come true" some kind of subjunctive mood?

---

Thanks, guys. By following your answers and comments, I found this: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178493/a-dream-come-true-is-it-correct

Comment: As per stangdon's answer, it just so happens that ***come** is the past participle of **to come**  [which]  looks exactly like the bare infinitive*. For a well-known example where the past participle *isn't* the same as the infinitive, consider the same construction in the noun phrase [*the word **made** flesh*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+word+made+flesh%22) in the Bible.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

"A myth **come** true" is a noun phrase, not a complete sentence.

You are correct in that if it were a complete sentence, the verb would have to be correctly conjugated for the subject.  In this case, *come* is the past participle of *to come*, because it's being used like an adjective (although you are also correct that for *to come*, the past participle looks exactly like the bare infinitive), and the phrase is using [*[whiz-deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/whiz-deletion/info)*].  You can think of it as
*(This is)* **a myth** *(which has)* **come true.**

Comment: +1 although I would have added that it is a pun on the idiom 'a dream come true'. Myths can't really come true because (1) they wouldn't be a myth if they were true, and (2) myths are legends from the *past*, so they can't *become* anything. Things like dreams (or hopes) can come true because they are forward-looking.

Comment: What is ‘whiz-deletion’?

Comment: @gidds: It essentially means leaving out "this is." See https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/whiz-deletion/info

Comment: Ah, I see. Could that be edited into the answer?

Comment: It's possible for a notion to be a myth at some point in time, and for reality to later match the notion at some other point in time.  While that would mean that the myth would cease to be a myth, there's no general expectation that "an X that becomes Y" continue to be an X. In some cases, the X would continue to be an X, but in many other cases it wouldn't be.